# QAction.setEnabled(False) unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, testing, pyqt5, pytest, python-unittest

I have ascertained that making a `QAction` disabled does not in fact prevent code from being able to run `activate()` on it, which strikes me as curious. So I want to make a helper subclass:

```
class DeactivatableAction(QtWidgets.QAction):
    def activate(self, event):
        if self.isEnabled():
            super().activate(event)
```

This seems to work in an app I'm working on, in practice. Then I wanted to include testing of this functionality (pytest):

```
@unittest.mock.patch('PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction.activate')
def test_deactivatable_action_should_only_superactivate_if_enabled(mock_super):
    import gen_fmwrk.deactivatable_action as d_action
    
    QtWidgets.QApplication([]) # without this, I get a complaint about "Application not initialized"
    
    da = d_action.DeactivatableAction()

    da.setEnabled(False)
    # da.setDisabled(True) - NB same effect as previous line

    assert not da.isEnabled() # this fails!
    da.activate(None)
    assert not mock_super.called # this also fails
```

I realise this is a sort of disembodied way to run PyQt5 code... but I'd still expect to be able to disable a QAction in a pytest context like this. What's going wrong, and is there a solution?

Comment: About your "curious" point: disabling an action doesn't limit its functionality programmatically, it only prevents user interaction, just like widgets: if a line edit is disabled, you can still use `setText`.

Comment: A fair point... but you might want to have the option of using a deactivatable action. The main point at issue remains...

Comment: The "complaint" about the missing QApplication is not just a meaningless alert. All elements directly related to the UI (aka: the running system, including screens, DPI, etc) require an *existing* instance of QApplication in order to properly query it about UI related aspects. QAction (at least before Qt6, where it was moved to QtGui) is a QtWidget class, so it requires a QtWidgets application (aka, QApplication). Your code didn't "complain" even without the assignment because an instance of the application existed at some point, but your code didn't work because it didn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `QtWidgets.QApplication([])` is not assigned to a variable so it will not be constructed correctly causing unexpected behavior. Change to

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
```